# create view that handle multiple fields in one field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a database with natural composite keys we would like to remove the surrogate key (Id) in the database, but not change the REST api too much. (e.g. still cache fields with Id, and get based on an Id)

Then have a view that abstact the difference, it could look like this:

```
create MyView
as
select key1 + '#' + key2 as Id, Name
```

and a query like this

```
select * from MyView where Id = '3#5'
```

And that would perform very poorly without some kind of hint or different view.

Is there a standard way to help the database resolve this?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE Key1 = 3 AND Key2 = 5`?

Comment: @Larnu yes that is what I would like to end up with. I would just prefer to begin with '3#5' because of my C# code.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is your Csharp code.

Comment: Just offtopic and not about what you asked, but why to remove surrogate key?

Comment: @Arvo you know it is the religious debate. The database team wants to remove it the developers wants to keep it because we have a REST api. So I am just investigating if there are any easy middle-ground.

Comment: If you *really* must have a column with the expression `key1 + '#' + key2`, and that's the column you want to use in the `WHERE` when you query said `VIEW`, then I suggest you make the `VIEW` schema bound, and then you can add an `INDEX` to the view on `Id`; if it's unique then it would be a good candidate for a clustered unique one.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, I think that was what I was looking for. Would you mind making it the answer?